# How to calculate "running total" in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given a table

```
ID FRUIT
-- -----
1  APPLE
2  BANANA
3  PEAR
4  APPLE
5  APPLE
6  PEAR
```

I want to get this

```
ID FRUIT RUNNING_TOTAL
-- ----- -------------
1  APPLE     1
2  BANANA    1
3  PEAR      1
4  APPLE     2
5  APPLE     3
6  PEAR      2
```

(going in the ID order, the first time we encounter a given fruit we set the value of the RUNNIN_TOTAL for that row to 1; the second time we encounter a given fruit, RUNNIN_TOTAL is 2, and so on).

I think I need to first add a column like this:

```
alter table Fruits add RUNNING_TOTAL int null
```

Then set the values for the new column with some thing like this

```
update Fruits set RUNNING_TOTAL = ...
```

but I am not sure how to complete the last statement. Can someone help? I am using SQL SERVER 2008, but a portable solution would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? `MySQL`, `Postgres`, `sql server 2008`, etc?

Comment: Updated the question. It's SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Great! Thanks :) Max's answer should do the trick for 2008. Window Functions are the way to go for this type of thing. 2008's implementation of Window Functions is pretty limited, but I believe Row_Number() was in place for that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, fruit, row_number() over (partition by fruit order by id) as running_total
from fruits
order by id
```

And then,

```
alter table Fruits add RUNNING_TOTAL int null

update fruits set running_total = subquery.running_total
from fruits
inner join (
 select id, row_number() over (partition by fruit order by id) as running_total
 from fruits
 )subquery on fruits.id = subquery.id

select * from fruits
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select f.*, row_number() over (partition by fruit order by id) as seqnum
      from fruits f
     )
update toupdate
    set running_total = seqnum;
```

I wouldn't really call such a column "running_total".  It seems more like a "sequence_number" to me.  "Running_total" suggests a cumulative sum.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Will try your solution tomorrow. +1 to you.

Also good comment on the column name. This is not the real column name I will use, but for the example purposes, sequence is indeed better.